# How to use Skip() and Take() in paging C# correctly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am still currently debugging the system becauae it seems to load all the data. My system has 4218 records. I have successfully used the Skip and Take in the system but the problem is that it only loads the first 10 records. How to call the other records? I want to do the Server Side Pagination.

This is the entity class:

```
public List<NonconformingServiceModel> GetAllNSIssue(int UserID, int pageNumber = 1)
        {
           

            using (SIRManagementSystemEntities _entities = new SIRManagementSystemEntities())
            {
                NonconformingServiceModel NSModel = new NonconformingServiceModel();
                var date1 = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0);
                List<NonconformingServiceModel> result = new List<NonconformingServiceModel>();

                var userData = (from _user in _entities.Administrators where _user.UserID == UserID select _user).FirstOrDefault();

                if (userData != null)
                {
                    if (userData.UserType == 1 || userData.UserType == 0 || userData.UserID == 38)
                    {
                        result = (from _NSDetails in _entities.NonconformingServices
                                  join _creator in _entities.Administrators on _NSDetails.CreatedBy equals _creator.UserID
                                  join _SIRDetails in _entities.SIR_InitialDetail on _NSDetails.NS_ID equals _SIRDetails.NSCCRefID into _sir
                                  from _SIRDetails in _sir.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                  select new NonconformingServiceModel
                                  {
                                      ID = _NSDetails.NS_ID,
                                      Type = _NSDetails.Type,
                                      Category = _NSDetails.Category,
                                      Reason = _NSDetails.Reason,
                                      Remarks = _NSDetails.Remarks,
                                      ModeThru = _NSDetails.Mode,
                                      DateDelivered = _NSDetails.DateDelivered,
                                      LoadingDate = _NSDetails.LoadingDate,
                                      DateIssue = _NSDetails.DateIssue,
                                      Origin = _NSDetails.Origin,
                                      Destination = _NSDetails.Destination,
                                      CartonNumber = _NSDetails.CartonNumber,
                                      ShipmentNumber = _NSDetails.ShipmentNumber,
                                      ShipperName = _NSDetails.ShipperName,
                                      ConsigneeName = _NSDetails.ConsigneeName,
                                      Address = _NSDetails.Address,
                                      NSGroup = _NSDetails.NSGroup,
                                      NSCode = _NSDetails.NSCode,
                                      OtherType = _NSDetails.OtherType,
                                      CreatedByID = _NSDetails.CreatedBy,
                                      CreatedByName = _creator.FirstName + " " + _creator.LastName,
                                      SIRCode = _SIRDetails.Code == null ? "" : _SIRDetails.Code,
                                      SIRDateIssue = _SIRDetails.IssueDate == null ? date1 : _SIRDetails.IssueDate,
                                      SIRDueDate = _SIRDetails.DueDate == null ? date1 : _SIRDetails.DueDate,
                                      Status = _SIRDetails.Code == null ? 0 : _SIRDetails.Status
                                  }).ToList();

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = (from _creator in _entities.Administrators
                                  join _NSDetails in _entities.NonconformingServices on _creator.UserID equals _NSDetails.CreatedBy
                                  join _mapping in _entities.CCNSDEPTMappings on _NSDetails.NSCode equals _mapping.NSCode
                                  join _SIRDetails in _entities.SIR_InitialDetail on _NSDetails.NS_ID equals _SIRDetails.NSCCRefID into _sir
                                  from _SIRDetails in _sir.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                  where _creator.Department == userData.Department || _mapping.ConcernDeptID == userData.Department || _creator.Department == userData.SecondDept || _mapping.ConcernDeptID == userData.SecondDept
                                  select new NonconformingServiceModel
                                  {
                                      ID = _NSDetails.NS_ID,
                                      Type = _NSDetails.Type,
                                      Category = _NSDetails.Category,
                                      Reason = _NSDetails.Reason,
                                      Remarks = _NSDetails.Remarks,
                                      ModeThru = _NSDetails.Mode,
                                      DateDelivered = _NSDetails.DateDelivered,
                                      LoadingDate = _NSDetails.LoadingDate,
                                      DateIssue = _NSDetails.DateIssue,
                                      Origin = _NSDetails.Origin,
                                      Destination = _NSDetails.Destination,
                                      CartonNumber = _NSDetails.CartonNumber,
                                      ShipmentNumber = _NSDetails.ShipmentNumber,
                                      ShipperName = _NSDetails.ShipperName,
                                      ConsigneeName = _NSDetails.ConsigneeName,
                                      Address = _NSDetails.Address,
                                      NSGroup = _NSDetails.NSGroup,
                                      NSCode = _NSDetails.NSCode,
                                      OtherType = _NSDetails.OtherType,
                                      CreatedByID = _NSDetails.CreatedBy,
                                      CreatedByName = _creator.FirstName + " " + _creator.LastName,
                                      SIRCode = _SIRDetails.Code == null ? "" : _SIRDetails.Code,
                                      SIRDateIssue = _SIRDetails.IssueDate == null ? date1 : _SIRDetails.IssueDate,
                                      SIRDueDate = _SIRDetails.DueDate == null ? date1 : _SIRDetails.DueDate,
                                      Status = _SIRDetails.Code == null ? 0 : _SIRDetails.Status
                                  }).ToList();

                   //   var  _result = (List<NonconformingServiceModel>)result.GroupBy(x => x.NSCode).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).ToList().Skip((pageNumber - 1) * 10).Take(10);
                    }
                    var _result = result.GroupBy(x => x.NSCode).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).ToList().Skip((pageNumber - 1) * 10).Take(10);

                    foreach (var item in _result)
                    {
                        if (item.Status == null || item.Status == 0)
                        {
                            if (item.SIRCode != "")
                            {
                                DateTime dueDate = item.SIRDueDate.Value;
                                DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
                                if (now.Date > dueDate.Date)
                                {
                                    item.FormatIssueDate = "late";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    item.FormatIssueDate = "not";
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                item.SIRCode = "";
                                item.SIRDateIssue = null;
                                item.SIRDueDate = null;
                                item.Status = 0;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            item.SIRID = (from _sirDet in _entities.SIR_InitialDetail where _sirDet.Code == item.SIRCode select _sirDet.sirID).FirstOrDefault();
                            item.SubmissionDate = (from _sirDet in _entities.SIR_InitialDetail where _sirDet.sirID == item.SIRID select _sirDet.SubmissionDate).FirstOrDefault();
                            item.CEDueDate = (from _sirCA in _entities.SIR_CorrectActDetail where _sirCA.Cor_SIRID == item.SIRID select _sirCA.CEDueDate).FirstOrDefault();
                            item.FormatIssueDate = "submitted";
                        }
                        item.TypeName = (from _type in _entities.DDNSTypes where _type.TypeID == item.Type select _type.Label).FirstOrDefault();
                        if (item.Type == 19)
                        {
                            item.TypeName = item.OtherType;
                        }
                        item.CategoryName = (from _cat in _entities.DDCategories where _cat.SIRCAT_ID == item.Category select _cat.Label).FirstOrDefault();

                        var deptArray = (from _mapping in _entities.CCNSDEPTMappings
                                         join _dept in _entities.Departments on _mapping.ConcernDeptID equals _dept.DeptID
                                         where _mapping.NSCode == item.NSCode
                                         select _dept.DeptID).ToList();

                        var deptCode = (from _mapping in _entities.CCNSDEPTMappings
                                        join _dept in _entities.Departments on _mapping.ConcernDeptID equals _dept.DeptID
                                        where _mapping.NSCode == item.NSCode
                                        select _dept.DeptCode).ToList();

                        item.ConcernedDeptArray = deptArray;
                        item.ConcernedDeptName = deptCode;

                        item.Company = (from _user in _entities.Administrators
                                        join _dept in _entities.Departments on _user.Department equals _dept.DeptID
                                        where _user.UserID == item.CreatedByID select _dept.Company).FirstOrDefault();
                    }

                    return _result.ToList();
                }
                return null;

            }
        
        }
```

This is the view model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SIMS.Model.Models
{
    public class NonconformingServiceModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public byte Type { get; set; }
        public string TypeName { get; set; }
        public string OtherType { get; set; }
        public byte Category { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public string OtherCategory { get; set; }
        public string Reason { get; set; }
        public string Remarks { get; set; }
        public string ModeThru { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateDelivered { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LoadingDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateIssue { get; set; }
        public string ConcernedDeptString { get; set; }
        public List<int> ConcernedDeptArray { get; set; }
        public List<string> ConcernedDeptName { get; set; }
        public string Origin { get; set; }
        public string Destination { get; set; }
        public string CartonNumber { get; set; }
        public string ShipmentNumber { get; set; }
        public string ShipperName { get; set; }
        public string ConsigneeName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string NSGroup { get; set; }
        public int CreatedByID { get; set; }
        public string CreatedByName { get; set; }
        public int CreatedByDept { get; set; }
        public int UserType { get; set; }
        public string NSCode { get; set; }
        public byte? Status { get; set; }
        public int? SIRID { get; set; }
        public string SIRCode { get; set; }
        public DateTime? SIRDateIssue { get; set; }
        public DateTime? SIRDueDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? SubmissionDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CEDueDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DetectionDate { get; set; }
        public string FormatIssueDate { get; set; }
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public int? Company { get; set; }
    }
    }
```

This is the controller class:

```
public ActionResult GetAllNSLogDetails(int UserID)
        {
            JsonResult _json = new JsonResult();
            NonconformingServiceManager _NSManager = new NonconformingServiceManager();
            _json.Data = _NSManager.GetAllNSIssue(UserID);
            _json.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
            return _json;
        }
```

This is the view:

```
<!-- Begin Page Content -->
<div class="container-fluid">

    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="/Home/Dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Nonconforming Service</li>
        </ol>
    </nav>

    <div class="card shadow mb-4">
        <div class="card-header py-3 d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-between">
            <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Nonconforming Services Log</h6>
            <div class="text-right">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info" onclick="window.location.reload();">Show All Data</button>
                <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".modal-filter-table" class="btn btn-outline-info"><i class="fas fa-filter"></i>Sort by</button>
                <button type="button" onclick="CreateNewConcern()" class="btn btn-outline-primary"><i class="far fa-plus-square"></i> Create New NS</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="card-body table-responsive">
                <table id="NonconformingServiceLogGrid" class="table table-hover" style="width:100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Date Created</th>
                            <th>NS Code</th>
                            <th>SIR Code</th>
                            <th>Date Issue</th>
                            <th>Due Date</th>
                            <th>Submission Date</th>
                            <th>Type</th>
                            <th>Category</th>
                            <th>Concerned Dept.</th>
                            <th>SIR Status</th>
                            <th>CE Due Date</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Date Created</th>
                            <th>NS Code</th>
                            <th>SIR Code</th>
                            <th>Date Issue</th>
                            <th>Due Date</th>
                            <th>Submission Date</th>
                            <th>Type</th>
                            <th>Category</th>
                            <th>Concerned Dept.</th>
                            <th>SIR Status</th>
                            <th>CE Due Date</th>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

All answers will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to call this api again with ```pageNumber = {value}``` also in your view, you need something like next or previous. On click of these, you will maintain state of pageNumber and request the same api again with different pageNumber.

Comment: Also while implementing pagination, one needs to send total count of data. This info is used inside view to show how many more pages/data is left on server to be fetched.

Comment: Why did you mention "C++" in the question title?

Comment: My bad. I edited my question. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Your action is missing the parameters to get the paging details from whoever calls your API like :
public ActionResult GetAllNSLogDetails(int UserID, int pageNumber=1, int pageSize=50)
Then you should be able to parse correct entities using that info. Like:
Entities.Skip(pageNumber*pageSize).Take(pageSize)

Here's one document that should help you most:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Assuming some form of relational database behind the scenes, there's also the problem that *tables are inherently unordered*. So unless you specify some specific ordering criteria (which needs to uniquely position every row for consistency purposes) `Skip` and `Take` are ill-defined. I see no attempt to apply any kind of order to your queries here so they effectively (no matter what page is asked for) decay to "give me 10 arbitrarily selected results"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You required one Pagination Class as per below example:

```
Response.cs

public class Response<T>
    {
        public Response()
        {
        }
        public Response(T data)
        {
            Succeeded = true;
            Message = string.Empty;
            Errors = null;
            Data = data;
        }
        public T Data { get; set; }
        public bool Succeeded { get; set; }
        public string[] Errors { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
```

Second class is `PageResponse.cs`

```
public class PagedResponse<T> : Response<T>
    {
        public int PageNumber { get; set; }
        public int PageSize { get; set; }
        public int TotalPages { get; set; }
        public int TotalRecords { get; set; }
        public int TotalFilteredRecords { get; set; }
        public PagedResponse(T data, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
        {
            PageNumber = pageNumber;
            PageSize = pageSize;
            Data = data;
            Message = null;
            Succeeded = true;
            Errors = null;
        }
    }
```

In controller you just need to fetch the data like below:

```
[HttpGet]
            public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllDetailAsync(int pageNumber)
            {
       int pageSize=10;
                
                var pagedData = await _Service.GetData(pageNumber, pageSize);
    
                PagedResponse<List<MyModel>> pagedResponse = new(pagedData, pageNumber, pageSize);
                pagedResponse.TotalRecords = await _Service.GetTotalRecords();
    
                int totalPages = pagedResponse.TotalRecords / pagedResponse.PageSize;
    
                if ((pagedResponse.TotalRecords % pagedResponse.PageSize) != 0)
                {
                    totalPages++;
                }
    
                pagedResponse.TotalPages = totalPages;
    
                return Ok(pagedResponse);
            }
```